# Autosizing not expanding box size in angular

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So I'm working on an autosizing function for textareas to create a nice UI experience, and I'm having an issue with a set up that I found.

I found this working version online here:

http://www.brianchu.com/blog/2013/11/02/creating-an-auto-growing-text-input/

Clearly you can see that this works. So I converted it over to angular, and have been messing around with it, but I'm not exactly sure what I am doing that is incorrect.

I'm working with it as a directive, and I'm running all the code on compile, so that should be putting all the elements and objects together smoothly shouldn't it?

I've placed my "in-progress" code below along with the location of the fiddle where I've been spit balling all this.

**fiddle**

https://jsfiddle.net/Mr_Pikachu/snszc0Lu/4/

**Current Code**

```
var a = angular.module('app', []);
a.directive('autoGrow', function($log, $compile, $document){
    return {
        compile : function(elem, attrs){

            // define variable and function
            var textContainer, textareaSize, input;


            // set the parent class and recompile
            input = angular.element('<textarea class="textarea-autogrow"></textarea>');
            textareaSize = angular.element('<div class="textarea-size"></div>');
            elem.append(input);
            elem.append(textareaSize);
            elem.addClass('textarea-container');

            var autoSize = function(){
                $log.log('fired');
                textareaSize.innerHTML = input.value + "\n";
            };
            autoSize();
            input.bind('input', autoSize);
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It looks like you're getting a console error: `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`, looking into this more.

Comment: @MannfromReno Sorry about that, I had the wrong link up there. I have edited it to the correct one, or just change the updated version from 3 to 4

Comment: I'm not getting anything logged when trying `$log.log(input.value)`

Comment: hmmm, should be getting something though shouldn't you?

Comment: `$log.log(input[0].value);` was returning correctly the value from the input

Comment: That's it! `input => input[0]` and `textareaSize => textareaSize[0]`. if you put it as an answer I will give you the credit for the find. Thank you!

Comment: Great! Glad I could help find the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we talked about your issue was getting the input's value, you should be using:

`input[0].value`

so this will be changed from:

`input` to `input[0]` and `textareaSize` to `textareaSize[0]`